# Custom Metrics and Losses: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' raised during training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to implement a custom metric function as well as a custom loss function. Both implementations are face the same issue, so I am going to focus this post in just one of them.

My goal is to access the value of a tensor during the fit method in order to make calculations based on said values stored in both y_true and y_pred. **These calculations cannot be done using built-in Keras backend functions**.

As an example, we have the dummy code below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric

x, y = list(), list()
for _ in range(10):
    x.append(np.arange(10))
    y.append(np.random.randint(0, 2))


x = np.reshape(x, (len(x), 1, len(x[0])))
y = np.asarray(y)

class custom_metric(Metric):
    def __init__(self, name = 'custom_metrics', **kwargs):
        super(custom_metric, self).__init__(name = name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name = 'tp', initializer = 'zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None):
        self.test(y_true, y_pred)
        # In a real application, new_metric would be a function that depends on
        # the values stored in both y_true and y_pred 
        new_metric = 0.1 
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(new_metric))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        self.true_positives.assign(0.)

    def test(self, y_true, y_pred):
        tf.print(y_true)
        print(y_true.numpy())

model = Sequential([
    LSTM(5,
         input_shape = (np.asarray(x).shape[1], np.asarray(x).shape[2]),
         return_sequences = True,
         recurrent_initializer = 'glorot_uniform',
         activation = 'tanh',
         recurrent_dropout = 0.2,
         dropout = 0.2
        ),
    Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer = 'adam',
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy', custom_metric()]
)

model.fit(
    x, y,
    epochs = 1,
    batch_size = 1
)
```

I wrote this dummy function `test` just to illustrate the issue. If only `tf.print` is used, the code runs and the values in the tensors are printed on `stdout` after the fit is done. However, is I try something like `y_true.numpy` or `print(y_true.numpy())` the code returns

`AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

I have tried several methods from several StackOverflow and Github threads, including combinations of `sess = tf.Session()` with `.eval()`, `tf.GradientTape`, but somehow failed to implement any of them successfully.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer to it. I don't know why yet but the code works using `tf-nightly 2.2.0-dev` version. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38038

Answer (score 1):

For tensorflow<2.0 graph mode is by default, In order to run in eager mode you have to enable it at the beginning by:

```
import tensorflow as tf  #<--- first import 
tf.enable_eager_execution()   #<-- immidiately followed by this, before you start defining any model
.
.
.
...rest of the code
```

**Eager-tensors have .numpy() function.**

But even if you do this, may be the tf.keras.Model.fit() method disbales it somewhere internally. Because:

This works:

```
def test(self, y_true, y_pred):
    if tf.executing_eagerly():  #<--- This is False
        print(y_true.numpy())
    else:
        print(y_pred)
```

This also:

```
def test(self, y_true, y_pred):
    print(y_pred)
```

But, this doesnot:

```
def test(self, y_true, y_pred):
        tf.print(y_true)
        print(y_true.numpy())
```

If you want to do any further calculations on y_true, then you can either do it using tensorflow ops in graph mode :

```
class custom_metric(Metric):
    def __init__(self, name = 'custom_metrics', **kwargs):
        super(custom_metric, self).__init__(name = name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name = 'tp', initializer = 'zeros')
        self.lol_value = self.add_weight(name = 'lol', initializer = 'zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None):
        self.test(y_true, y_pred)
        # In a real application, new_metric would be a function that depends on
        # the values stored in both y_true and y_pred 
        new_metric = 0.1 
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(new_metric))

    def result(self):
        return self.lol_value

    def reset_states(self):
        self.true_positives.assign(0.)
        self.lol_value.assign(0.)

    def test(self, y_true, y_pred):
        print(y_pred)
        self.lol_value.assign_add(100)
```

or if you truly, absolutely want numpy then use **[tf.numpy_function()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function)**, which converts a normal numpy calculation into it's equivalent graph code.

```
def func_x(varx):
    #print(x)
    return (varx+1).astype(np.uint8)


class custom_metric(Metric):
    def __init__(self, name = 'custom_metrics', **kwargs):
        super(custom_metric, self).__init__(name = name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name = 'tp', initializer = 'zeros')
        self.res = self.add_weight(name='loop_counter', initializer='zeros', dtype=tf.uint8)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None):
        self.test(y_true, y_pred)
        # In a real application, new_metric would be a function that depends on
        # the values stored in both y_true and y_pred 
        new_metric = 0.1 
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(new_metric))

    def result(self):
        return self.res

    def reset_states(self):
        self.true_positives.assign(0.)

    def test(self, y_true, y_pred):
        self.res.assign(tf.numpy_function(func=func_x, inp=[self.res], Tout=[tf.uint8]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy()` method should exist for tensor objects when eager execution mode is enabled under tf2.x. Maybe this link could be of help to you: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#object-oriented_metrics

Comment: It works outside of a custom function / model fit, but it does not work either in the compilation or fit of a model